# How can I cancel a users radiobutton selection, after a confirm dialog cancel selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, label-for

In a bigger project, I have a group of radiobuttons, which updates the text in a textarea. Sometimes however, I need to let the user choose if they really want to change the text.

I'm using hidden radiobuttons, and only the labels are showing. I've been able to present the confirm dialog, and prevent the change of text in the textarea, but I have not been able to actually stop the radiobutton from checking the newly clicked element. I've tried to save a reference to the previously checked radiobutton, but I suspect that it is already to late in the code. To further illustrate, I have made a JSFiddle. There should never be a mismatch between button texts and text in the area, once one has been loaded.

http://jsfiddle.net/e0bxnghc/1/

So is there a way to cancel the user's selection of the radiobutton?

HTML:

```
<nav id="selectors" class="segmented-button">
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" value="car" id="radio1">
    <label for="radio1" class="first">Car</label> 
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" value="boat" id="radio2">
    <label for="radio2">Boat</label> 
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" value="plane" id="radio3">
    <label for="radio3">Plane</label> 
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" value="train" id="radio4">
    <label for="radio4" class="last">Train</label> 
</nav>

    <textarea id="output">output area</textarea>
```

javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectors label').click(function() {    
        var element = $(this).prev();
        var confirmed = false;
        var previousSelected =  $("input[name=group-1]:checked");
        var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to change the text?");
        if (r == true) {
            $("#output").val(element.val());

        } else{
            previousSelected.checked = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning false in the else should do it:

```
else{
        previousSelected.checked = true;
        return false;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/e0bxnghc/2/)**

Comment: Wow... That actually worked. but I have no clue of why. Do you mind providing a clue? Consider the answer accepted (in 10 minutes, you are fast!)

Comment: Returning false essentially nullifies the click event. You could also have used `.preventDefault()` in the same place.

Comment: Also worked like a charm in the bigger picture. I feel smart for getting so damn close, and even smarter for taking the time to ask a question, and provide simplified code. 12 hours into my work day, this was a lifesaver :)

Comment: This knowledge will certainly be very useful in the future! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Sorry about that delay in accepting the answer. I forgot.

Answer (score 1):

Simply returning 'false' from the radio button click event rolls back the action. We don't need to save the previously selected radio button. Browser does this for us:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[name=Group]').click(function () {
            var confirmation = confirm('Are you sure you want to change the default message?');
            if (!confirmation) {
                return false;
            }
        })
    });
```